# Modifying Dictionary Values (Lists)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Please post any suggestions that I can do, please do not post any code.

```
Test = [1, 2, 3]
DTest = {'a':[], 'b':[]. 'c':[]}
```

I want to write some code so that each element in Test is placed into the empty lists in DTest so that it looks like this: (assuming Test and DTest is always the same length)

```
DTest = {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[3]}
```

I was thinking that I should use a nested "for" loop, but I end up with this:

```
DTest = {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[1, 2, 3], 'c':[1, 2, 3]}
```

Please don't post any code, only suggestions on what I can do.
Thanks

Comment: How are you determining which value from `Test` should go under which key in `DTest`?  `dict` keys don't have an order.

Comment: And with the request for "no code", is this homework?

Comment: If you post your existing code we can help you find the problem with it.

Comment: Use only one loop Start for loop with i = 0 to 2. Get value from test and put into Dtest.

Comment: Note that dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

[zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) Test and DTest and use [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to get it in the form that you want.

respecting your request not to show code. let me know if you decide otherwise

Comment: Also, you'll probably need an ordered collection of keys, otherwise the keys to values mapping will be random.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not tested it is just an idea to build a dictionary.

```
      testVal = Test.get(i) //Get items from List
   for j in list(DTest.keys()): // Get Keys from Dictionary
       DTest[j] = testVal  // Update Dictionary values.
```

Hope It may helps :)

Comment: `.items()` returns a list of tuples that contains both keys and values